# ratebar star in tablerow

Tags: android, rate

I just want to have a `RatingBar` with 5 stars in a `TableRow` but it always come out 8 stars.
but I have already used `android:numStars="5"` to notify it.

Also, it fills 7.5 star instead of 4 stars with `android:rating="4"`
whatever I have changed just meaningless to the layout.

My XML is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/image_row"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/grid_image"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/text_row"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp" 
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grid_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxWidth="140dp"
                android:text="Summary" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/rate_row"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/product_rating"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:max="5"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="4"
                android:stepSize="1" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are using the rating bar inside table row. According to reference docs the children of tablerow take match parent as their width. So instead you can nest a horizontal linearlayout inside this table row which in turn will embed rating bar as follows :

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/rate_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/product_rating"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:max="5"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="4"
                android:stepSize="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:numStars="5"
           android:stepSize="1.0" />
```